# Obtain NameIdentifier (sub) in AD FS

Tags: powershell, adfs

I would like to obtain the sub (NameIdentifier) of a user for an AD FS application in order to allow him to identify in an application's user table.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/id-tokens#using-the-id_token

This is completely On-Premises set up.

Answer (score 0):

From memory, its returned in the id_token but you can always get it via the ADFS userinfo endpoint.

This always returns the subject claim as specified in the OpenID standards.

Comment: I was looking for a simple way like `Get-ADUser` with Powershell to add new users sub to the users table in the application. If not, is there a way 'easily' consume the ADFS userinfo endpoint as an admin?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/42131776/9922